# Kill MS SQL process from java prepared statement?

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement, kill

I try to kill a MS sql server (8) process with a prepared statement in java. But I always receive the exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

Any ideas?

```
public void killBlockingProcess(int spid)   {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("kill ?");
        ps.setInt(1, spid);
        boolean res=ps.execute();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(this + ",killBlockingProcess: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try {ps.close(); } catch (Exception exp){}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kill` accepts only numbers, not parameters.  Run:

```
"kill " + spid
```

Against the connection and it should work.  Alternatively, let SQL expand the parameter:

```
"declare @query varchar(max)
set @query = 'kill ' + ?
exec (@query)"
```